# How do I determine how much permissions my application needs?

Tags: c#, permissions, windows-services

I have been asked what permissions a Windows service (written in C#) needs. Because it is now running under the domain administrator account, it has full access to everything on the domain. Now we want to run the app under a new account specifically created for the app. My question is, what permissions should we give to the app? Is there an easy way to check it besides reading thousands of lines of codes (determining what the app actually does)?

Note: I am not the one who has developed the app.

Comment: You're stuck with reading the code I'm afraid. Newer (whatever they're calling metro apps) have to ask for permissions but old style Windows service code could be doing anything

Comment: I have heard an app called PermCalc. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165077%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
But it supports apps up to .net 3.5. Are there any alternatives to do the same?

Comment: I think the easiest solution here is to ask the question 'is there any reason to NOT give the application administrator access?' Probably not. I would go ahead with creating an account for it and have the app run as administrator to avoid having to do it again later anyway. Mind you, someone SHOULD know what the application does.